# How to get the Coordinates of the Transparency in an Image

Tags: c#, image, transparency

I'm new to C#, and I have an image (of type Image in C#) that has a transparent border. I would like to get the coordinates of how much of that image has that transparency.

I know there is a property in C# called Color.Transparency (Here is the link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.transparent(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.transparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ), but I'm not sure how to actually use this to get the coordinates of where that transparency is.
It's not compiling to simply write the statement: Image.Color.Transparent

(P.s. the image is a PNG, and then transformed into a BMP, and I can use either file format to get these coordinates: http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-snagit-transparency-prior.html )

Thank you all!

Comment: What for? In order to trim the image?

Comment: No, I have a corresponding XML for the image, and some elements are based on the coordinates of this image, and I need to either add/ take away from the coordinates of these elements by the value of these transparent bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deal with Bitmap object, here is a way you can do it :

```
private static IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Point> GetTransparencyPoints(System.Drawing.Bitmap image) 
{
  for (int i = 0 ; i < image.Width ; i ++ ) {
    for (int j  = 0 ; j < image.Height ; j ++) { 

         Color color = image.GetPixel(i, j) ; 

         if (color == Color.Transparent) { 
            yield return new System.Drawing.Point(i, j) ; 
         }
    }
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me!